# Баг или фича? С++ mouse_event

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << endl << "0.1";
    while (true)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN))
        {
            while (true)
            {
                mouse_event(0x0002, NULL, NULL, 0, 0);
                mouse_event(0x0004, NULL, NULL, 0, 0);
                if (GetAsyncKeyState(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN))
                    goto br;
                Sleep(10);
            }
        }
        else continue;
    br:
        Sleep(10);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Работает, но есть баг. По сути это кликер, нажми и держи лкм и будет тебе кликать. Но есть одно НО! Оно не работает по нажатию лкм, работает по пкм (кликая левой кнопокй). В самом коде НЕТУ указания использовать пкм. Как решить эту проблему? Пробовал обратным способом, поменять все левые на правые, но толку ноль.

Comment: `goto` !.. зачем?.. я уже лет 15 как на C++ не писал и вопрос, что с `break` за это время произошло?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так понял, Вы проверяете в консоли, а она ловит mouseevents, чтобы такого не было, отключите выделение мышью в свойствах консоли
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проверил на этом коде:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        auto state = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON);
        if (state & 0x8000)
        {
            std::cout << ++i << '\n';
        }

        if (state & 0x0001)
        {
            i = 0;
        }

        Sleep(100);
    }
    return 0;
}
```